# Only display certain message from a string

Tags: c#, regex

```
[0][0][0]#[0]º[0][0][0][0][0][11]hello world[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]

[0][0][0][0]º[0][0][0][0][0][6]its me[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]
```

I am trying to only get the text from strings like the above, to get started I did:

```
lblMessage.Text = message.Remove(0, 32);
```

But I wouldn't know how to get the text after that until a "[" is found and remove everything after that as well, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Are the bracket really in the data?  Or are the brackets just being added by the editor you are using to view the data?

Comment: You need to learn about SubString and IndexOf methods of string. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: What is your expected result from the given string?

Comment: What if you `.Replace` the characters you don't want with an empty string?

Comment: They are in the data, expected result would be hello world and its me

Comment: Are the strings ASCII, or can they contain any valid text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [REGEX](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) like below :

```
string str = "[0][0][0][0]º[0][0][0][0][0][6]its me[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]";
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^a-zA-Z ]", "").Trim();
```